# How can I write / append data without changing any formatting of an Excel Sheet?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I am currently facing one issue. I have an excel sheet with some particular formatting. I have to make a program which can read the data from the sheet and analyze it from my database, fetch some more data and write back to the same sheet.

I know how to read and write using `PHPExcel`. But I don't know how to write on a given sheet.

Comment: Select the sheet you want to edit using `setActiveSheetIndex()` or `setActiveSheetIndexByName()` or similar methods.... or you can access cells in a specified sheet without changing the active sheet using something like `$objPHPExcel->getSheet(1)->getCell('A1')` or `$objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Sheet 2')->getCell('A1')`

Comment: On Uploading the file attribute changes the name of the file extension to .tmp how to resolve that.

Comment: [Move](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) the file to whatever filename/folder you want first, that's nothing to do with PHPExcel, just simply part of uploading a file